# What are the horns of freedom?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Vol 2,

> Stakar tells Yondu that Yondu will not hear the horns of freedom when Yondu dies, and the colors of Ogord will not shine above Yondu's grave, because Yondu had trafficked in children.

We know that

> the colors of Ogord refer to the House of Ogord, of which Stakar is a member.

**But what are the horns of freedom?**

Comment: Your first spoiler block happens in first 15 minutes or so of the movie; there's no need to hide it.  I don't think the second spoiler block is even mentioned in the movie, and it's completely irrelevant to the movie anyway; why hide it?

Comment: @jwodder Others have complained in the past for failing to obscure things that occur in the first ten minutes of a movie. Then the second block contains part of the answer. If you want to remove the spoiler masks, you may.

Comment: I assume he is saying Yondu will not receive a Ravenger's funeral.

Comment: @JackBNimble If you are correct, then the horns of freedom would be the song father and son by Cat Stevens.

Answer (score 4):

Having just seen the film, and not having found anything online, it seems that by "horns of freedom" Ogord refers to the funeral ceremony the Ravager captains did in Yondu's honour, especially the fireworks:

[image]

and the salutations:

[image]

The "colours of Ogord" would then refer to Ogord's fireworks<sup>1</sup>. In that scene, Peter says (and Kraglin's reaction confirms) this is a proper Ravager funeral, which would mean that the Ravagers, and especially Ogord, thought Yondu redeemed for breaking the Ravager code before.

<sup>1</sup> One can say it refers to the House of Ogord, which appears in comics, but since this wasn't made clear in the film, I'm omitting it.

Comment: No. No. No. Ogord refers to the [House of Ogord](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starhawk_(comics)), and the colors are therefore the colors of the House of Ogord, which were represented by fireworks at the funeral. You were on the right track, but missing details.  More importantly, **you did not explain what the horns of freedom are**, which means that you have not answered the question.

Comment: @CodeMed "[by 'horns of freedom'] Ogord refers to" - I'm saying it refers to the whole ceremony.

Answer (score -1):

If you listen to the soundtrack, right as Yondu dies, there are horns playing. My guess is that they are the horns of freedom which he is hearing as he dies.

Comment: Not exactly. The Horns of freedom refers to the ones played at his funeral and not when he dies. The soundtrack has no connection to it.